# iOS UIAlertView giving EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, uialertview, exc-bad-access, reachability

I have searched for awhile and tried many things, but I cannot get this error to go away. I have a table that is refreshed by a pull down method. I also use Apple's Reachability to determine internet connectivity. When I run my application WITH internet, and then while the app is running, shut the internet off, my app crashes trying to display a UIAlertView. Although, when I start my app WITHOUT internet and then turn on internet while the app is running and turn it back off, the app does not crash and everything works as it should. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The error occurs on the [message show] line.

Edited code:

```
- (void)loadCallList {

NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.wccca.com/PITS/"];

NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:10.0];
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

if (theConnection) {

    NSLog(@"Reachable");

    self.headerHeight = 45.0;

    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:theURL];
    xpathParser = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:data];
    NSArray *elements = [xpathParser searchWithXPathQuery:@"//input[@id='hidXMLID']//@value"];

        if (elements.count >= 1) {

            TFHppleElement *element = [elements objectAtIndex:0];
            TFHppleElement *child = [element.children objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *idValue = [child content];

            NSString *idwithxml = [idValue stringByAppendingFormat:@".xml"];
            NSString *url = @"http://www.wccca.com/PITS/xml/fire_data_";
            NSString *finalurl = [url stringByAppendingString:idwithxml];

            xmlParser = [[XMLParser alloc] loadXMLByURL:finalurl];

            [callsTableView reloadData];
        }
    }

else {

    NSLog(@"Not Reachable");

    self.headerHeight = 0.0;

    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Internet Connection"
                                                      message:@"Please check your internet connection and pull down to refresh."
                                                     delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [message show];
    [message release];
}

[pull finishedLoading];
}
```

Comment: try [autorelease] on your alertView rather than release

Comment: What happens when you turn Zombies on? And you're saying all the other alert views work fine? Are you also saying that the one that causes the crash is working some of the time? Finally, is everything running on the main thread?

Comment: sure that it is by the alerts?comment it and test it.

Comment: Autorelease does not work. I have already had zombies on and that's what error I get. All other alertviews work fine, yes. It only crashes  the app when I start the app up WITH internet and then mid-running, shut off internet and try to refresh. If I start the app WITHOUT internet, then turn internet on/off/on/off however many times, everything works fine. And yes, everything is on the main thread.

Comment: @JonErickson you mean not running ARC right? I see `release` calls in your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the following method using sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler: as the method to download data from the URL. It seems to work fine, I can get the else clause to fire, either by messing up the URL or making the timeout interval .1 seconds.

```
    NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.wccca.com/PITS/"];

    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:5];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:theRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil) {
            //do whatever with the data.  I converted it to a string for testing purposes.
            NSString *text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"%@",text);
        }else{
            NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
            UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Internet Connection" message:@"Please check your internet connection and pull down to refresh." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [message show];
        }
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

1. You shouldn't be using Reachability to determine whether there is an internet connection. Reachability is only useful to determine when an offline connection comes back online. Really. Making the networking calls is sometimes enough to power up the radios and connect so if you try to pre-check whether there is an internet connection the radios will remain off.
2. The second problem is that no synchronous networking calls can be made on the main thread. This includes Reachability and [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:xxx]. Make them on a secondary thread using Grand Central Dispatch, NSOperationQueues, NSURLConnections, or NSThreads. Otherwise your application can lock up if the network isn't in good shape and the system watchdog timer will kill your app.

Comment: How do you suggest I check internet connectivity then?

Comment: You don't check. You make a connection and if it fails you handle the failure. You have to handle the failure anyway so it's not really more work, but just a different way of thinking.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. I will work on changing it over to that. Do you know why my AlertView is failing though? I should have nothing to do with that....

Comment: I think you are probably locking up in the Reachability or network calls for more than 20 seconds and the system watchdog timer is killing you.

Comment: Yes, do the networking on secondary threads using NSURLConnections, Grand Central Dispatch, NSOperationQueues, or NSThreads. Or use a third-party networking library.

Comment: Alright, one other question! Thanks for your time. I have switched my syntax over to handle a connection failure instead of Reachability. It works except for one thing, when I turn off my internet, the connection doesn't fail and doesn't go to the "else {}". You can see the code above. Even when I turn my internet off,  it still goes down the "if (theConnection} {}". I am probably missing something really easy...

Comment: The if (theConnection) statement just tests whether you were able to initialize an NSURLConnection object -- it will return TRUE even if you give it a totally bogus URL or your internet isn't connected.

Comment: How do I need to change it so that if there is internet, do this and if there isnt internet, do that?

Comment: do I need to use the delegate methods; 
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection and
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error ??

Comment: Yes. Read Apple's docs on using NSURLConnection. There are a few non-obvious situations you should deal with, like redirects.